# Calculating probablity of a boolean circuit

Tags: probability, reference-request, boolean-algebra

For a given Boolean algebraic expression, how to compute the probability that the output will be logical one from the given probabilities of its input combinations? Can there be any probability distribution formed for the output? What is this branch of mathematics called? How to find out special properties of two Boolean expressions which have equal probability?

Any reference literature dealing with probabilistic analysis of Boolean algebra will be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01183339/document

Comment: Was this reference useful to you ?

Comment: Hi Jean, I was going through this reference. It was helpful for me in understanding the basics. This article deals with finding the probability of a specific Boolean function _f_ of _n_ variables from a set of all Boolean functions $2^{2^{n}}$. In my specific case, the Boolean function _f_  is fixed and I am interested in only analyzing the probability of '1' in its truth able w.r.t to the probabilities of the input variables. Something more specifically as density of truth.